# What is DPR in chrome developer tools? How is it used and why?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-emulator, web-deployment, chrome-dev-editor

I was trying to emulate a device. I don't understand what does DPR do. For example if I want to add my mobile with resolution 720×1440. I write 360×720 to fit it on my laptop screen with 100% zoom meaning that now it occupies 360×720 pixels of my laptop screen. I think that DPR is used to fit higher resolution devices into other screens at reduced screen resolution that is in my case DPR should be 2. I have done many experiments and I think DPR should be set for the laptop to assume that this area with a 360×720 on my screen is actually 720×1440. However if DPR is what I think, then the window.screen.width; must return 720. But it still returns 360. This theory fits as long as I see the pre-added device list of the chrome dev tools. What is the real logic behind DPR? How can I really add my 720×1440 device? what length width must be set for my device?

Answer (score 2):

> There isn’t a one-to-one mapping between CSS pixels and device pixels.
> Some devices use four smaller pixels to one CSS pixel, arranged in a
> 2x2 grid. Some use one, and some use nine (3x3 grid). There can even
> be a fractional ratio between the two, like 1.5 or 2.25.
>
> The number of device pixels that make up a CSS pixel in one direction
> is its Device Pixel Ratio (DPR). You can interpret this as the width
> (or height) of the grid of device pixels that fit inside one CSS
> pixel.

> **Here’s how I understand it.**
>
> Firstly, higher resolution devices have more pixels available to
> display the image.
>
> Let’s say there were two devices that were 4 inches wide. Device 1 can
> fit 2000 pixels in that space, and device 2 can only fit 1000.
>
> Device 1 is 2000 pixels wide, so it could display the image with width
> 2000w perfectly. But device 2 is 1000 pixels wide, so it can’t display
> this image perfectly. It would have to “average out” the colour values
> of some pixels. There’s no point serving this device with the 2000w
> image: it’s just unnecessary data downloading. You’d give it a smaller
> image.
>
> Device 2 would even struggle with the image with width 1200w. It would
> still have to average out some pixels. But it’s a lot better than the
> 2000w image, and a lot smaller too.

Source: https://tomroth.com.au/dpr/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Edited comment. Thanks for your suggestion :)